# How to vectorize a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I have this dataframe :

```
aaa=read.table(text="variable value   
  X3CO     24.88994
  X3CO     25.02366
  X3CO     24.90309
  X3CS     25.70630
  X3CS     25.26748
  X3CS     25.19539
  X3CD     26.95723
  X3CD     26.84726
  X3CD     26.23144
  X3CSD    36.95251
  X3CSD    36.04091
  X3CSD    36.90476
  X5CO     25.44123
  X5CO     24.97586
  X5CO     24.86076
  X5CS     25.71570
  X5CS     26.10244
  X5CS     25.39033
  X5CD     27.67509
  X5CD     27.18986
  X5CD     26.93682
  X5CSD    36.26529
  X5CSD    34.88553
  X5CSD    33.97910
  X7CO     24.71426
  X7CO     24.08444
  X7CO     23.97058
  X7CS     24.55734
  X7CS     24.56562
  X7CS     24.75898
  X7CD     27.14260
  X7CD     26.65704
  X7CD     26.49533
  X7CSD    33.89882
  X7CSD    32.91092
  X7CSD    32.79199
  X9CO     26.86141
  X9CO     26.42649
  X9CO     25.83506
  X9CS     28.17368
  X9CS     27.27401
  X9CS     26.58814
  X9CD     28.88915
  X9CD     28.32598
  X9CD     28.27136
  X9CSD    34.61352
  X9CSD    35.84190
  X9CSD    35.80329",header=TRUE)
```

Do you know if there is a way of vectorizing this dataframe into vectors using the "variable" levels ?

This process would be equivalent to doing this manually :

```
c(c(24.88994,25.02366,24.90309), c(25.70630,25.26748,25.19539),...)) 
corresponding to 
c(c(X3CO,X3CO,X3CO),c(X3CS,X3CS,X3CS),...))
```

Comment: `aggregate(value ~ variable, aaa, as.vector, simplify = FALSE)`? This creates a `list` of vectors in your "value" column. Alternatively, `with(aaa, split(value, variable))` perhaps? I don't quite understand your question. Can you describe your end goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `split()` function to create a list of data frames each containing only one level and then extract the vectors from this list:

```
aaa.sp <- split(aaa, aaa$variable)
aaa.sp[[1]]$variable
aaa.sp[[1]]$value
```

Answer (score 1):

For your given data frame:

```
aaa$value
```

since it's already grouped (if not necessarily sorted) by `variable`.

For a data frame that isn't already in groups:

```
aaa[order(aaa$variable), "value"]
```

Comment: ok but how to make individual vectors using the variable levels (3values per vector)